# Issue Hosting Silverlight Application on IIS 7.5

Tags: silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an ASP.NET web application (.NET 4.0) that has a few pages, one page with a silverlight application in it.

When I debug locally, the silverlight app works fine. When I deploy to my web server (Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5), the silverlight app will not display.

I get an exception in Application_Error saying the following files are missing:

```
clientaccesspolicy.xml
crossdomain.xml
```

I have found a few things on the net that aren't very helpful - they say they need to be in C:\inetpub\wwwroot. I don't have a 'Default' website in IIS7.5 and I don't have these folders?

Where can I find them and where should I put them?

Please help, as this is very urgent. Many thanks.

EDIT: So I have tried doing what the link in my comment suggests. Some more info: I have a Silverlight-enabled WCF service that the Silverlight app uses in order to work.

Do I need to do anything special when deploying my app with an .svc file? I remember having to enable access to .svc files back in IIS5, but I don't know if that's necessary in IIS 7.5?

Hope this extra info helps. If you need any code snippets etc, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I've created the two files as per this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(VS.95).aspx. I've put them both in the root of my website, but still no cigar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, worked it out - a slightly embarrassing and annoying problem..............

The service reference in the Silverlight application had a client address of 'http://localhost......', which was added by Visual Studio when I added the service reference.

I found a [blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/04/05/managing-service-references-in-silverlight-applications-for-different-environments.aspx) by Tim Heuer describing the issue. I had to set the client address to a relative one, using '../Service.svc' in the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig.

Very annoying, sort that out please Microsoft!!!